# does actionview not work with jruby?

Tags: jruby, actionview

does actionview not work with jruby? here's what I tried

rvm use 2.2.2
ruby tests.rb
ruby: ruby 2.2.2p95
phantomjs: 1.9.2
tests: foo\n\n
rvm use jruby
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19
ruby tests.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:7 warning: already initialized constant HTML_ESCAPE
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:8 warning: already initialized constant JSON_ESCAPE
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:9 warning: already initialized constant HTML_ESCAPE_REGEXP
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:10 warning: already initialized constant HTML_ESCAPE_ONCE_REGEXP
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:11 warning: already initialized constant JSON_ESCAPE_REGEXP
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:133 warning: already initialized constant UNSAFE_STRING_METHODS
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:111 warning: already initialized constant URI_REGEXP
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:166 warning: already initialized constant ASSET_EXTENSIONS
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:180 warning: already initialized constant ASSET_PUBLIC_DIRECTORIES
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb:14 warning: already initialized constant BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb:23 warning: already initialized constant TAG_PREFIXES
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb:25 warning: already initialized constant PRE_CONTENT_STRINGS
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb:6 warning: already initialized constant JS_ESCAPE_MAP
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb:34 warning: already initialized constant JOIN
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb:35 warning: already initialized constant NEW
ruby: jruby 1.7.19
phantomjs: 1.9.2
tests: foo\n\n

My tests.rb contains

## a test script

class App
  require 'action_view'
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

# does soms prerequisite checks
  def pre_checks
    puts "ruby: "+`ruby --version`[0..12]
    puts "phantomjs: "+`phantomjs --version`
    puts "tests: "+truncate(DATA.read.to_s.gsub("\n",'\n'), length: 65)
  end

end

app = App.new
app.pre_checks
**END**
foo

Answer (score 0):

you should upgrade to JRuby **1.7.21** ... seems like the `$LOAD_PATH` 'expanding' issue present in 1.7.19 (which is since than fixed)